# Disable covered up portion of monitor

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, resolution

On a dual monitor setup, one of the screen is covered up by another screen due to insufficient desk space.

Trying to disable part of the screen which is covered up with Intel HD Graphics Control Panel.

Both screens' native resolution are 1080p.

1. Added custom resolution to the screen which was covered up, 1672x1080 in this case.
2. Set the scaling to maintain aspect ratio

This method worked somewhat. I managed to disable part of the screen but I only want to disable the part which is covered up, ie. left side.

There is also an option to center the image but I can't find anything to right align or left align my screen.

I'm on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit running i3-6100 on-board graphics only.

Is it even possible to achieve what I'm trying to do?